# No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem to a known managed provider native type

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

This is driving me crazy.

> No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem to a known managed provider native type

When I try to pass data from a listbox into a database through insert into, I get this error. The data in the listbox is extracted from the database as well.
The insert looks like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@driver",DriversJourney.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

I tried it with selecteditem(), selectedValue.ToString()), selectedIndex, SelectedValue.

```
 public partial class FindDriver : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\RideShare.mdf;Integrated Security=True");//set connection as a variable
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataReader dr;


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                if (Session["username"] == null)
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("~/Account/FindDriver.aspx");
                    }

                else
                    {
                        labelWelcome.Text = "Welcome " + Session["UserName"] + "!".ToString();
                    }

        }

 protected void search(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Driver WHERE City = '" + JourOrigin.SelectedItem + "' ";
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dr.Read();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            Session["city"] = JourOrigin.SelectedItem.ToString();
            Response.Redirect("~/Account/FindDriver.aspx");
            NoCity.Visible = false;

        }
        else
        {
            DriversJourney.Items.Clear();
            DriversJourney.Items.Add("No Drivers in selected city, try another city");
            NoCity.Visible = true;
            NoCity.Text = "No drivers in selected city, please try another city";
        }
        con.Close();
    }

 protected void JourneyAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\RideShare.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
        {


           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Journey(JourneyOrigin, JourneyDestination, Date, Time, PassengerUserName, DriverUserName) VALUES (@origin, @destination, @date, @time, @driver, @passenger)");
           cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
           cmd.Connection = connection;
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@origin", JourOrigin.SelectedItem);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@destination", JourDestination.SelectedItem);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", Calendar.SelectedDate);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", date.SelectedItem);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@driver", DriversJourney.SelectedValue);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passenger", Session["username"].ToString());
           connection.Open();

           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your exception does not match the code you've given.  Include the entire call stack.

Comment: `SelectedItem` is an item, so it won't work. When you used `DriversJourney.SelectedValue`, what error did you get? @Zer0: The error in the title of this post is the exception you'd get [if you tried to pass a ListItem as a parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095689/no-mapping-exists-from-object-type-system-web-ui-webcontrols-listitem-to-a-known).

Comment: @Santi What?!  He's doing `ToString()`.  So he is passing a string not `SelectedItem`.  No idea what you mean.  But I do agree that is what the exception is stating which is why I'm confused.  In other words that code should work fine.  And I don't believe it's the cause of the exception.

Comment: I get the exact sane error whatever i put after DriversJourney. I also get this: An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: @Zero0 Oh you're right, I hadn't even noticed, I assume that OP must've pulled this exception prior to adding the `.toString()`.

Comment: @Santi or a different line of code.  That's why I asked for the callstack.  Nothing wrong with the code provided.  Certainly doesn't match exception message.

Comment: @Mateusz That line of code is not your problem.  Can't help unless you provide more code and a callstack.

Comment: Agreed. @Mateusz - long story short, I highly doubt this line is the only issue. There should be nothing wrong with doing a `SelectedItem.Text` or a `SelectedValue`, etc, at least none that would return this issue.

Comment: I assumed this is the problem as it's the only listitem on the page. I'll add the code above by editing it

Comment: I added the code, the error shows in cmd.executenonquery();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines of code are part of your problem:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@origin", JourOrigin.SelectedItem);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@destination", JourDestination.SelectedItem);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", date.SelectedItem);
```

Please cast them to the correct type or use `SelectedValue`.

That exception is telling you that you're setting a parameter to an object of type `ListItem`, and you can't possibly insert that into the database.

Break when the exception is thrown (with a debugger attached) and look at the `Parameters` collection ensuring their values are of the correct type.  For now you're looking for a parameter that has a value of `ListItem`.  But I'd check them all for correctness while there.

Answer (score 0):

From your edited version of the question, you are trying to send parameter values that cannot be translated when actual SQL command is constructed. Or simply, these values do not have simple type as string, int, bool etc.

```
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@origin", JourOrigin.SelectedItem);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@destination", JourDestination.SelectedItem);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", Calendar.SelectedDate);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", date.SelectedItem);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@driver", DriversJourney.SelectedValue);
```

Double check the lines above and select the actual values (not entire objects, as SelectedItem seems to be).

More general, you should try to separate UI from business logic. Business logic method should work only with relevant data such as identifiers, names etc. and not UI elements such as `ListItem`s.